# Box2d collide only with one body

Tags: java, filtering, box2d, collision

Sorry if there is another thread like this one, but i cannot find a solution..

I have a box2d game and i need to make one body to collide ONLY with the player and nothing else.
Can you help me? How to define the mask bits, or the groups?

Comment: You'll need more specifics and possibly some code, so that people can understand your problem and help you.

Comment: http://blog.xyris.ca/2009/11/25/check-the-filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (i write on LibGDX). I use setContactFilter(). I implemented this interface and override shoudCollide()

```
public class BackgroundContactFilter implements ContactFilter {
 @Override
 public boolean shouldCollide(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB){
  return false;
 }

}
```

All interactions are disabled with this code.

I hope that this would be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a great article that will walk you through everything you need to know about masks and groups:

http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2011/07/box2d-tutorial-collision-filtering/